# Rutas con parametros Angular 6

Tags: angular, rutas, angular6

Tengo un componente que es un boton y que guarda objetos en una variable llamada Microfonos. Y quiero que el boton pase el objeto a otro componente para despues mostrar detalles de ese objeto en especifico. Pero no me esta funcionando.

button-menu.component.ts

```
export class ButtonMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()Microfonos:any;
  @Input()NombreClasificacion:any;

  micObj:any

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

button-menu.component.html

```
<div class="btn-group dropright">
    <button type="button" class="btn beige dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-display="static" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{NombreClasificacion}}</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-left">
        <button *ngFor="let mics of Microfonos" class="dropdown-item beige text-center" type="button" [routerLink]="['/presentacion',mics]">{{mics.nombre}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

app-routing-module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
  path:'menu',
  component: MainComponent,
  },
  {
    path:'bajo',
    component: MenuBajoComponent
  },
  {
    path:'guitarra',
    component: MenuGuitarraComponent
  },
  {
    path:'presentacion/:objMic',
    component:PresentacionMicComponent
  }
];
```

presentacion-mic.component.ts

```
export class PresentacionMicComponent implements OnInit {

  objMic:any;

  constructor(private rutaActiva:ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.rutaActiva.params.subscribe( params => {
      this.objMic = params['mics'];
    });
    console.log(this.objMic);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Se supone que en mis rutas defino que el componente presentacion tiene un parametro, ese parametro se lo paso con el boton desde la linea de [routerLink]. Pero en la consola me aparece que el parametro que le mando es undefined.

Answer (score 0):

creo que esta respuesta te puede ayudar

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176463/comunicaci%C3%B3n-entre-componentes-que-se-muestran-en-diferentes-vistas-angular-5)

Mira la comunicación entre componentes para angular 6