# ¿Como usar en componente hijo una variable del padre en Angular?

Tags: angular, objeto, component, binding

Buenos dias/tardes,
  Gracias a [Comunicación entre componentes que se muestran en diferentes vistas Angular 5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176463/comunicaci%c3%b3n-entre-componentes-que-se-muestran-en-diferentes-vistas-angular-5) soy capaz de crear en un componente hijo en su html los datos.
Me intento explicar:
1) en el padre hago

```
 <div *ngIf ="autenticado">                  
    <button name="boton_Respuesta " *ngIf ="autenticado" >Responder{{hilo.idEnfermedad}}</button>
    //quiero pasar hilo
                            <app-form-respuesta [HiloEnMostrarHilos]="hilo"></app-form-respuesta>
  </div>
```

como veis mi hijo usara HiloEnMostrarHilos

2) html del hijo hago,

```
<p>form-respuesta works!</p>
<div>
    {{HiloEnMostrarHilos.enfermedad}}
</div>
```

y me lo muestra sin problemas.
Pero....
3) si quiero operar en fichero.ts

```
 @Input() HiloEnMostrarHilos;

  @Output() enviarInfoPadre =new EventEmitter<any>();// no esta terminado, de momento no lo uso, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=df0eH9mM9nU   minuto 19

  //private aux = this.HiloEnMostrarHilos;


  constructor() { 


    console.log("form_respuesta --->>>"+ this.HiloEnMostrarHilos);

  }
```

aquí " this.HiloEnMostrarHilos " no me muestra nada más que ...

```
form_respuesta --->>>undefined
```

en la consola para depurar. No es lo que quiero pero la page la carga bien.
Sin embargo se hago

```
    console.log("form_respuesta --->>>"+ this.HiloEnMostrarHilos.enfermedad);
```

ni me carga la página y da error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'enfermedad' of undefined
    at new FormRespuestaComponent (form-respuesta.component.ts:23)
    at createClass (core.js:31985)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:31807)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:44210)
    at createEmbeddedView (core.js:44069)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45632)
    at Object.debugCreateEmbeddedView [as createEmbeddedView] (core.js:44881)
```

Estoy aprendiendo Angular. No se que prueba hacer. Creo otra variable y le paso el valor del @input y tampoco. Y con [1] tampoco. No entiendo por que el html lo recoje sin problemas y el ts no.

gracias.

Comment: Los componentes son asíncronos, quiere decir que tu constructor se ejecuta antes que el `@input()`. Lo puedes ver en el html por que este está ligado a los cambios del `ts` y los aplica automáticamente, en cambio el constructor sólo se ejecuta una única vez.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de Roberto Murguia es adecuada siempre que estes bindeando algo diferente a undefined antes de que el ngOnInit se ejecute, sin embargo si no es el caso te seguirá arrojando undefined.

Puedes probar algo como esto:

```
@Input() set HiloEnMostrarHilos(HiloEnMostrarHilos) {
if (HiloEnMostrarHilos) {
this_HiloEnMostrarHilos = HiloEnMostrarHilos;
}
}
_HiloEnMostrarHilos;
```

En este caso tendrías que usar la variable _HiloEnMostrarHilos en tu HTML pues tendrá el valor recibido por input.