# Pasar parámetro en ngOnInit

Tags: angular

Tengo un app y dentro de ella uso un componente

```
<body>
  Esta es mi app echa en Java y esta vista tiene el id ${id}
  <app-list></app-list>   => aqui llamo a mi componente de angular
</body>
```

Me gustaría pasarle el id a mi componente para leerlo en el ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log("vamos" + this.id) => undefined
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176463/comunicaci%c3%b3n-entre-componentes-que-se-muestran-en-diferentes-vistas-angular-5/)

Comment: lo q comentas es si el padre es otro componente, en mi caso es algo diferente, he intentado adaptar lo que me comentas pero no llama al método

Comment: Lo que necesitas es un @Input(), no se pasan valores al `onInit`. Y si no puedes usar un ancestro común, lo correcto es usar un servicio con un método que te devuelva un observable al que te puedes subscribir en todos los componentes que necesites, y un método que permita enviar datos a través de dicho observable. Si el `@Input()` proviene de algún lugar asíncrono (como una llamada http) es más que posible que no tengas el dato cuando carga el componente... para eso puedes usar un *setter*  en tu `@Input()` que se ejecutará cuando llegue el dato... o probar a usar `onChanges`, depende :)

Comment: modificada mi pregunta con la solución

Comment: @sirdaiz No hay problema si escribes una respuesta a tu propia pregunta y la marcas como aceptada, modificar una pregunta para añadir la respuesta, en cambio, es algo que NO se debe hacer. ¿Podrías deshacer el último cambio y añadir la solución como respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Solución

```
<body>
  Esta es mi app echa en Java y esta vista tiene el id ${id}
  <app-list id="59"></app-list>   => aqui llamo a mi componente de angular
</body>


@Input()
id: number;

ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log("vamos" + this.id) => works!
}
```